# Algorithm for presenting combinations easy to read

Tags: algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

Given a list of products/computers to buy I would like to give the customer an easy overview of the possible spec combinations.

My input (on the left in the image below) is a list of combinations.
The desired output (on the right in the image below) is a graphical representation.

The amount of data is limited so performance is not critical

**QUESTION**

Is there an algorithm or method that will help me produce this?

[image]

EDIT: updated image

Comment: `Order By`? I.e. `Order By Size, Ram, Hdd` then when displaying combine same values in each column (`15", 15", 15"...` -> `15"`)

Comment: In SQL you could use Group By to collapse same fields into one

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Will this work for both examples?

Comment: @ginkul Thanks, how would you construct this SQL query?

Comment: @Rasmus something like this will work in PostgreSQL.
Let's say you have a table `computer` with fields `size`, `ram`, `hdd`.
In the first case:
`SELECT size, ram, STRING_AGG(hdd, '\n') FROM computer GROUP BY size, ram;`.
`STRING_AGG` is an aggregate function, wich concatenates hdd's with `\n`.
The second case:
`SELECT size, STRING_AGG(ram, '\n'), STRING_AGG(hdd, '\n') FROM computer GROUP BY size;`

Comment: @ginkul Indeed you are correct (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/27aea7/2) - in the first case. But i'm looking for a single query/function that can handle both cases (and many more)

Comment: @Rasmus I see. Then try this: `SELECT size, STRING_AGG(DISTINCT(ram), '\n'), STRING_AGG(DISTINCT(hdd), '\n') FROM computer GROUP BY size;`

Comment: what happens if you have for couples (size, ram): ```[(15,8),(15,16),(13,8),(13,16),(12,16)]```?

Comment: @grodzi It is unclear to me what you mean

Comment: @ginkul Works great, except for this case: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c252e/1 Any suggestions?

Comment: @Rasmus it was pretty tough, but I think I got it. Gonna make an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer in PostgreSQL will look like this:

```
-- CREATE TABLE computer(
--   size VARCHAR (50),
--   ram VARCHAR (50),
--   hdd VARCHAR (50)
-- );

SELECT size as size, 
  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT(ram), '\n') as ram, 
  hdd as hdd 
  FROM (
    SELECT size as size, 
      STRING_AGG(DISTINCT(ram), '\n') as ram, 
      STRING_AGG(DISTINCT(hdd), '\n') as hdd 
      FROM computer 
      GROUP BY size, ram
    ) AS result 
  GROUP BY size, hdd;
```

In this subquery we're grouping by size and ram, because, as I understood, there is always one size in a row, and we can always collapse hdd's. It may be that some of ram's are equal, so now we're grouping by hdd to collapse those ram's, and by size to keep them unique.

I hope this makes sense and answers your question.

Comment: This solves the OP problem. However it will not scale to 10+ columns

Comment: @Rasmus oh, man, this is getting interesting :D I will try to seek a solution